# Circular reference when using new s3notifications.LambdaDestination in cdk

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm running into a cyclic issue with this

```
props.incomingBucket.addEventNotification(EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, new s3notifications.LambdaDestination(this.incomingHandler));
```

This is the error I get:

> throw new Error(`'${target.node.path}' depends on '${this.node.path}' (${cycle.join(', ')}). Adding this dependency (${reason}) would create a cyclic reference.`);

I have incomingBucket in stack A, and incomingHandler in stackB, this `props.incomingBucket.addEventNotification(EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, new s3notifications.LambdaDestination(this.incomingHandler));` is in stackB but it’s running into this issue. However, `props.incomingBucket.grantReadWrite(this.incomingHandler);` this has no issues, so I’m not entirely sure what’s going on…

This is my full stack:

```
export interface LambdaProps {
    readonly env: DeploymentEnvironment;
    readonly stackName?: string;
    readonly stage: string;
    readonly vpc: EC2Vpc;
    readonly incomingBucket: Bucket;
    readonly blobsBucket: Bucket;
    readonly blobsTable: Table;
    readonly identExtractor: Extractor;
}

export class LambdaStack extends DeploymentStack {

    public readonly apiLambda: IFunction;
    public readonly dropboxLambda: IFunction;
    public readonly incomingHandler: IFunction;

    constructor(parent: core.App, name: string, props: LambdaProps) {
        super(parent, name, {
            softwareType: SoftwareType.INFRASTRUCTURE,
            ...props
        });

        this.incomingHandler = new Function(this, "IncomingHandler", {
            code: .... stuff here,
            handler: 'handlers.incoming_lambda',
            runtime: Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
            timeout: core.Duration.seconds(30),
            environment: {
                .... stuff here
            }
        });

        // // new blobs in the incoming bucket trigger lambda event
        // TODO ok this is causing a circular issue, need to figure out how to fix 
        props.incomingBucket.addEventNotification(EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, new s3notifications.LambdaDestination(this.incomingHandler));

        // grant permissions to the incoming lambda.
        props.incomingBucket.grantReadWrite(this.incomingHandler);
        props.blobsBucket.grantReadWrite(this.incomingHandler);
        props.blobsTable.grantReadWriteData(this.incomingHandler);

        props.identExtractor.taskQueue.grantSendMessages(this.incomingHandler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5760 there was a circular dependency issue.

Based on the https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/10426 it was resolved in the way that bucket depends on the lambda. I assume that you need to change your code equally - inject lambda into the bucket stack instead of injecting bucket into the lambda stack.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was resolved but... doesn't seem like it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't inject the lambda into the bucket stack because it would cause a circular import issue lol. The Lambda stack requires the bucket stack bucket.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I guess you can then "reverse engineer" addEventNotification CDK actions and do them on your own trying to avoid the circular dependency.